# Set TabItem header as TextBlock in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Right now I have something like this:

```
<TabItem Name="tbActive" Width="100" Height="100"  Header="Current" >
```

and in the code behind I set the Header -- so setting it above is a bit pointless

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Text = "Current";
tb.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(tb_MouseDown);
tbActive.Header = tb;
```

I don't want to use this code behind... I'd rather it all be XAML.  So how can I set the 4 textblock lines in my TabItem XAML ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<TabItem Name="tbActive" Width="100" Height="100">
    <TabItem.Header>
         <TextBlock Text="Current"
                    MouseDown="tb_MouseDown"/>
    </TabItem.Header>
</TabItem>
```